# "No student at your school can speak Russian or knows C++" / OR usage

Tags: meaning, grammar

I'm new at this forum and I love it already.

I had some doubts about the usage of "or" in terms of meaning.

If we have the sentence as follows:

```
"No student at your school can speak Russian or knows C++"
```

What does this *really* mean?

As far as I know, this means that there is an amount of students at my school and none of them speaks Russian. And, in addition, none of them knows C++.

However, today my English teacher told me that this means that there is an amount of students at my school and none of them speaks Russian ***or*** knows C++, but not both. Therefore, some students might not speak Russian but know C++, and some others might speak Russian but not know C++.

Is my teacher wrong? Or am I wrong? This doesn't make any sense to me.

Thank you.

Comment: Natural language is not like mathematics or formal logic; people will always be able to find ambiguity in a statement, and there is often more than one valid interpretation of any statement. This is one reason why legal language (for example, in official contracts) is so dense and overwritten.

Comment: This is not a question about the usage of _or_; the sentence is ungrammatical and therefore doesn't mean anything, so it's not surprising it's confusing. A correct sentence meaning (what I suppose is) the same thing would be _No student at your school can speak Russian or program C++_, since Conjunction Reduction requires a parallel active infinitive verb in the second clause. This sentence is almost unambiguous, following DeMorgan's Laws; it takes an effort to understand it incorrectly.

Comment: @choster natural language is a LOT like formal logic in some cases (at least simple ones), and I think this is exactly such a case.  It's almost unimaginable to me that a native English speaker would interpret the OP's sentence as the teacher did--if you wanted to express the teacher's meaning, you would say "and" instead of "or".

Comment: To add: I think I _would_ have an ambiguous interpretation for a sentence that wasn't a negative, so that's interesting.

Comment: If your English teacher really said “amount of students”, you should find a new English teacher.

Comment: "Amount of students" is not correct?